# Multiple ResultSet-s with single Statements in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

`Connection.createStatement()` has no parameters. Then we call `Statement.executeQuery()` to retrieve data.

Can we use single `Statement` instance for multiple different queries run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not concurrently. When you re-execute the statement, [the previous result set is closed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you're executing, well, the same SQL with different parameters.

Comment: Not with `Statement`, you are talking about `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`

Answer (score 0):

Try Statement createStatement(int resultSetType,
                          int resultSetConcurrency,
                          int resultSetHoldability)
resultSetHoldability=ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT